# scroll view content offset in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to find the y content offset from a javascript. The definition of content offset is:

> The point at which the origin of the content view is offset from the origin of the scroll view

Comment: What do you mean 'y content offset'? Do you mean the y offset of any particular element?

Comment: yea.. of an element say that I have an img which is at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` to know the X and Y co-ord of an element.

```
var X=element.offsetLeft;
var Y=element.offsetTop
```

for more help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetLeft

Comment: This will only give the position with respect to the element's parent. Not the actual position.

Comment: correct . so use element.offsetParent to get the parent  and then find parent's offsetleft and then calculate your element position.

Comment: @techfoobar: your solution is nice .

Comment: That you. :) But yes, using offsetTop is the gist of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code to find the position:

```
function findPos(obj) {
    var curleft = curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        curleft = obj.offsetLeft
        curtop = obj.offsetTop
        while (obj = obj.offsetParent) {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft
            curtop += obj.offsetTop
        }
    }
    return curtop;
}
```

You can call it like findPos(document.getElementById('myID'));

Check this URL for explanation: http://txt.binnyva.com/2007/06/find-elements-position-using-javascript/

Comment: Thanks for posting a fully working function. Just saved me fiddling with it.